# maintenance job frozen in executing state

Tags: sql-server-agent

I have several maintenance job stuck on my sql server , stuck from the 10th of may , what should I do first? I try to stop them from sql agent but nothing happens

I did a check with sp_whoisactive

have this  kind of statments 
(327853387ms)PREEMPTIVE_OS_AUTHZINITIALIZECON

update: I restarted the agent but the jobs after a while re appear with the ne execution (they are scheduled jobs)

Comment: do I have to reboot the whole sql server 2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end the solution was to restart sql service, the restart of the sql agent was not sufficient